# Python 3.11.3 - Web3 6.4.0 - Python reports that contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens does not have attribute buildTransaction

Tags: web3js, pancakeswap

I have now Python 3.11.3 and Web3 6.4.0 and I cannot use anymore my old code for buying/selling tokens in Pancakeswap because Python reports that contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens does not have attribute buildTransaction

How Can I modify my code for using it in Web3 6.4.0 ?

thanks

```
#this is for BUYING
    
    tokenToBuy = web3.to_checksum_address(tokenAddress)
    spend = BNBTokenAddress  #wbnb contract address
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)
    
    start = time.time()
    
    pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
    0, 
    [spend,tokenToBuy],
    walletAddress,
    (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)
    ).buildTransaction({
    'from': walletAddress,
    'value': web3.to_wei(float(snipeBNBAmount), 'ether'), #This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
    'gas': gasAmount,
    'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce,
    })

    try:
        signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key)
        tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction) #BUY THE TOKEN
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
   
    txHash = str(web3.to_hex(tx_token))


    #TOKEN IS BOUGHT

    checkTransactionSuccessURL = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=transaction&action=gettxreceiptstatus&txhash=" + txHash + "&apikey=" + bscScanAPIKey
    checkTransactionRequest = requests.get(url = checkTransactionSuccessURL)
    txResult = checkTransactionRequest.json()['status']


    if(txResult == "1"):
        print(" Successfully bought $" + tokenSymbol + " for " + style.BLUE + str(snipeBNBAmount) + " BNB - TX ID: ", txHash)
        time.sleep(10) #wait for tx to confirm
        
    else:
        print("Transaction failed: likely not enough gas.")
```

#THIS is for SELLING

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
spend = BNBTokenAddress #wbnb contract address
#Approve Token before Selling
start = time.time()
approve = sellTokenContract.functions.approve(pancakeSwapRouterAddress, tokenValue).buildTransaction({
            'from': walletAddress,
            'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
            'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),
            })

try:
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve, private_key=private_key)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print("Approved: " + web3.to_hex(tx_token))
except Exception as e:
  
    print("Already been approved")
    pass
return


#Wait after approve 5 seconds before sending transaction
time.sleep(5)
tokenSymbol = sellTokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
print(f"Swapping {tokenReadableBal} {tokenSymbol} for BNB")

time.sleep(5) # wait for approval to confirm

#Swaping exact Token for ETH 
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETH(
            tokenValue ,0, 
            [tokenContractAddress, spend],
            walletAddress,
            (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)

            ).buildTransaction({
            'from': walletAddress,
            'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
            'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),
            })

try:
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private_key)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print(f"Sold {tokenSymbol}: " + web3.to_hex(tx_token))
except Exception as e:
 
    print( "Price impact too high, can't be sold at this moment. Will retry shortly.")
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try build_transaction

```
walletAddress,
    (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)
    ).build_transaction({
```